# How to add animation-name css to Jquery show()

Tags: jquery, html, show

I am relatively new to JQuery and want to understand in depth. From the docs show() method is not taking any animation CSS definitions. Is it possible to display an element(say a div) dynamically with the "animation-name" as css.

Lets say I have my own custom animation using `key-frames`, my questions is how to apply this custom animation dynamically while displaying an element.. is there any Jquery method that does this?

Comment: I don't understand the question... sorry.

Comment: Not sure I even understand the question but if your looking to animate a div with CSS elements in the jquery this may help http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Check this http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. You can add/remove classes using jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass` methods and leave the animation to CSS.

Comment: Ya.. Lets say I have my own custom animation using     key-frames, my questions is how to apply this custom animation dynamically while displaying an element.. is there any Jquery method that does this?

Comment: I think you're looking for this method: http://api.jquery.com/queue/ - it allows you to put your custom functions calls ("keyframes") on calls queue. Otherwise - can you please rephrase your question and provide an example of usage, even in pseudocode, of what do you want to do.

Comment: thanks for your responses... I will do a bit of research on this and will rephrase my question....